# How To exclude vertex with label name = 'Kpi' in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

i have the next Query in GremlinDb:

```
g.V('61f4e0c0-2f17-4a0a-a874-ee7325c110e5').outE().has(label,'HasActionBook').inV().outE().has(label,'ActionBookHasSwimlane').inV().outE().inV()
```

and returns to me all items but i have a item with label 'Kpi' how to do to exclude this items with this label ?

thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `not` in front of a `hasLabel` step as in :

```
not(hasLabel('Kpi'))
```

Comment: thanks for your contribuation but i solved with other syntax and is this:

is in the next Response please see it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However you can replace the entire where step with just the not(hasLabel('Kpi')) which to me feels simpler.

Answer (score 0):

im solved it with this syntax.

```
g.V('61f4e0c0-2f17-4a0a-a874-ee7325c110e5').outE().has(label,'HasActionBook').inV().outE().has(label,'ActionBookHasSwimlane').inV().outE().where(has(label, neq('SwimlaneHasKpi'))).inV()
```